Does a USB-C male to USB-A female adapter draw power with no connected device or cable in the USB-A female end?
My car has 2 USB-C ports and I bought a UGreen USB-C to USB-A adapter to use it with USB-A flash drives and my phone (which has a micro-USB port) via a USB-A to micro-USB cable.
These USB-C ports seem to provide current even with the engine off.
As I would like, for convenience, to have the adapter always connected to the USB-C port, is there a chance that this adapter draws power even without a device or my USB-A to micro-USB cable connected to it and thus affect the car battery?

UPDATE: I've got a reply from Ugreen: "The adapter does not draw power from the car. Please don't worry about it. It is not suggested to use this adapter to charge your devices. Please use this adapter for data transmission only."

That one looks basic, but there are some crazy complicated cables around (usually very over-engineered and overpriced imo ;-) A USB power meter / USB digital tester could say for sure

It's a passive adapter (no converter chip, just two connectors wired together), so it doesn't need to draw power in general.
(It does have a single resistor on the 'CC' line on the USB-C end, acting as an indicator to the USB-C port that it should supply power at a certain voltage – I don't exactly understand how the circuitry works, but as far I understand from the Type-C specification and other sources, the amount of current that is used for sensing would take over 30 years to drain a car battery.)

I'd imagine that in some cases, the indicator to the USB-C port that it should supply power will make it supply power that it otherwise wouldn't, meaning that some power-conversion circuitry might be powered on. This power conversion circuitry will probably use more idle power than the cc resistors. It probably depends on your car /  USB-C host / charging device weather the power circuit is always on or only on when it detects something on the CC lines.

Thanks for your answer! I updated my question with the reply from Ugreen.
